# How to access the window instance in event function

Tags: javascript, events

I have a following code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
           <button id="but" >Click me</button>
        </div>
        <script>
            var ele = document.getElementById("but");
            ele.addEventListener('mousemove', myFunction);
            this.model = {
                'a': 'A',
                'b': 'B'
            }
            function myFunction(e) {
                alert(this.model.a);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I hover the button it throws an error because I can't access `model.a`. `this` seems to refer to the DOME element. How can I access `this.model` within that function?

Comment: You could say `ele.addEventListener('mousemove', myFunction.bind(this))`, but given that `this` is `window` at that point why are you setting `this.model` in the first place, rather than just `var model = {...}`?

Comment: Or just access it as `model.a`.

Comment: in my case i have use custom library and all other stored as instance i m not store data in window i have stored in my library instance(which i hv created in custom control)... in this case oly i need to access that model

Comment: but thanks however bind is working fine... thanks dude

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
           <button id="but" >Click me</button>
        </div>
        <script>

            this.model = {
                'a': 'A',
                'b': 'B'
            }           
            var ele = document.getElementById("but");
            ele.addEventListener('mousemove', e => alert(this.model.a));

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

'this' works in a very strange way in JavaScript, it points us to the object which call the function. I think you can use arrow function to fix it, because they have more traditional behavior with 'this'.

Comment: *"it points us to the object which call the function"* - Except in all the cases when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the window object.
So you should change myFunction to:

```
function myFunction(e) {
    alert(window.model.a);
}
```

Comment: there is any possible to another like passing model or anything else.. \

Comment: I'm not sure about passing parameters to the event handler, but if you already know the object is on the global scope, then just use the global object (aka window object)